# Upload images - Nodejs Paperclip and S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sequelize.js, paperclip

I want to upload an image to S3 and save to user record with NodeJS, just like the Rails Paperclip gem.

I believe this should be the process, but again I'm quite confused about how this package should work:

1. receive an image and resize by paperclip
2. save or update to S3
3. save file to `user` in DB

I have a Rails Postgres database, and users can upload an image, stored in S3, and reformatted with Paperclip gem. Here's how it is stored:

```
irb(main):003:0> user.avatar
=> #<Paperclip::Attachment:0x000055b3e043aa50 @name=:avatar, 
@name_string="avatar", @instance=#<User id: 1, email: 
"example@gmail.com", created_at: "2016-06-11 22:52:36", 
updated_at: "2019-06-16 17:17:16", first_name: "Clarissa", 
last_name: "Jones", avatar_file_name: "two_people_talking.gif", 
avatar_content_type: "image/gif", avatar_file_size: 373197, 
avatar_updated_at: "2019-06-16 17:17:12", @options={:convert_options=>{}, 
:default_style=>:original, :default_url=>":style/missing.png", 
:escape_url=>true, :restricted_characters=>/[&$+,\/:;=?@<>\[\]\ 
{\}\|\\\^~%# ]/, :filename_cleaner=>nil, 
:hash_data=>":class/:attachment/:id/:style/:updated_at", 
:hash_digest=>"SHA1", :interpolator=>Paperclip::Interpolations, 
:only_process=>[], 
:path=>"/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename", 
:preserve_files=>false, :processors=>[:thumbnail], 
:source_file_options=>{:all=>"-auto-orient"}, :storage=>:s3, 
:styles=>{:large=>"500x500#", :medium=>"200x200#", 
:thumb=>"100x100#"}, :url=>":s3_path_url", 
:url_generator=>Paperclip::UrlGenerator, 
:use_default_time_zone=>true, :use_timestamp=>true, :whiny=>true, 
:validate_media_type=>true, :adapter_options=> 
{:hash_digest=>Digest::MD5}, 
:check_validity_before_processing=>true, :s3_host_name=>"s3-us- 
west-2.amazonaws.com", :s3_protocol=>"https", :s3_credentials=> 
{:bucket=>"example", :access_key_id=>"REDACTED", 
:secret_access_key=>"REDACTED", 
:s3_region=>"us-west-2"}}, @post_processing=true, 
@queued_for_delete=[], @queued_for_write={}, @errors={}, 
@dirty=false, @interpolator=Paperclip::Interpolations, 
@url_generator=#<Paperclip::UrlGenerator:0x000055b3e043a8e8 
@attachment=#<Paperclip::Attachment:0x000055b3e043aa50 ...>>, 
@source_file_options={:all=>"-auto-orient"}, @whiny=true, 
@s3_options={}, @s3_permissions={:default=>:"public-read"}, 
@s3_protocol="https", @s3_metadata={}, @s3_headers={}, 
@s3_storage_class={:default=>nil}, 
@s3_server_side_encryption=false, @http_proxy=nil, 
@use_accelerate_endpoint=nil>
```

`user.avatar(:thumb)` returns:

> `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example/users/avatars/000/000/001/thumb/two_people_talking.gif?1560705432`

Now, I'm trying to allow the user to upload a new/change image through a react-native app, and the backend is Nodejs, which is relatively new to me.

I'm so confused about how to implement this, especially because the examples are all referencing Mongoose, which I'm not using.

Just to show how I'd successfully update the user, here is how to update `first_name` of the user:

```
users.updateUserPhoto = (req, res) => {

  let id = req.decoded.id
  let first_name = req.body.first_name

  models.Users.update(
      first_name: first_name,
      {
        where: {
          id: req.decoded.id
        }
      },
    ).then(response => {
        res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: { response } });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({ status: 500, err: error });
    })
}
```

Here is the package I found [node-paperclip-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-paperclip-s3), and here's what I'm trying to do:

```
'use strict'
let users = {};
const { Users } = require('../models');
let models = require("../models/index");

let Sequelize = require('sequelize');
let Paperclip = require('node-paperclip');
let Op = Sequelize.Op;
let sequelizeDB = require('../modules/Sequelize');

users.updateUserPhoto = (req, res) => {
  let id = req.decoded.id
  let avatar = req.body.avatar <- this is a file path

  models.Users.plugin(Paperclip.plugins, {
      avatar: {
        styles: [
          { original: true },
          { large:     { width: 500,  height: 500 } },
          { medium:    { width: 200, height: 200 } },
          { thumb:  { width: 100, height: 100 } }
        ],
        prefix:      '/users/{{attachment}}/{{id}}/{{filename}}',
        name_format: '{{style}}.{{extension}}',
        storage: 's3',
        s3: {
          bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
          region: 'us-west-2',
          key: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
          secret: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        }
      }
  })

  models.Users.update(
      avatar,
      {
        where: {
          id: req.decoded.id
        }
      },
    ).then(response => {
        res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: { response } });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({ status: 500, err: error });
    })
}
```

I've also tried something like this:

```
    models.Users.update(Paperclip.plugins, {
      avatar: {
        styles: [
          { original: true },
          { large:     { width: 500,  height: 500 } },
          { medium:    { width: 200, height: 200 } },
          { thumb:  { width: 100, height: 100 } }
        ],
        prefix:      '/users/{{attachment}}/{{id}}/{{filename}}',
        name_format: '{{style}}.{{extension}}',
        storage: 's3',
        s3: {
          bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
          region: 'us-west-2',
          key: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
          secret: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        }
      },
      {
        where: {
          id: req.decoded.id
        }
      },
    ).then(response => {
        res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: { response } });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({ status: 500, err: error });
    })
  })
```

I've tried:

```
let new_avatar = (Paperclip.plugins, {
      avatar: {
        styles: [
          { original: true },
          { large:     { width: 500,  height: 500 } },
          { medium:    { width: 200, height: 200 } },
          { thumb:  { width: 100, height: 100 } }
        ],
        prefix:      `/users/avatars/{{attachment}}/{{id}}/{{filename}}`,
        name_format: '{{style}}.{{extension}}',
        storage: 's3',
        s3: {
          bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
          region: 'us-west-2',
          key: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
          secret: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        }
      },
  })

  let data = {
    avatar: new_avatar
  }

  models.Users.update(
      data,
      {
        where: {
          id: req.decoded.id
        }
      },
    ).then(response => {
        res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: { response } });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({ status: 500, err: error });
    })
```

From the example in the link above, I don't understand how it is saving to S3, or how it's updating the database in the same way the Rails gem is creating that record.

Question :  how to save resized images + original in the exact same way that the Rails paperclip gem is saving to S3 AND the `user` record in the database.

I originally had this open for a 400 point bounty, and am more than happy to still offer 400 points to anyone who can help me solve this. Thanks!!

Comment: So your backend is still rails and the UI part is react native?

Comment: @Tarun Lalwami No, this mobile app has a NodeJS API and front end is react native. But the existing web app is Ruby on Rails, which is why paperclip was used to set up the user’s images.

Comment: any errors? I guess `models.Users.plugin` is undefined?

Comment: the auther of `node-paperclip` says  "_It currently only works with mongoose, but is set up to be easily extended to work with other databases._"  [repo](https://github.com/ballantyne/node-paperclip#node-paperclip)

Comment: Yes, undefined. I’ve tried several things, and essentially the resizing is not taking place in any format. Thanks for reading where I didn’t - I wonder what does ‘easily extend’ mean? I’m also not committed to this package - basically I just need to accomplish the resizing and save like they are currently being stored. Do you know any other ways I can accomplish this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The below code is for nodeJs.
    I have added an api to save an image from frontend to AWS S3.

I have added comments within code for better understanding.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: config.AwsS3SecretAccessKey,
    accessKeyId: config.AwsS3AccessKeyId,
    region: config.AwsS3Region
});

router
    .route("/uploadImage")
    .post(function (req, res) {

    //req.files.imageFile contains the file from client, modify it as per you requirement
    var file = getDesiredFileFromPaperclip(req.files.imageFile);
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + file.name;

    //before uploading, we need to create an instance of client file
    file.mv(fileName, (movErr, movedFile) => {
        if (movErr) {
            console.log(movErr);
            res.send(400);
            return;
        }
        //read file data
        fs.readFile(fileName, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err)
                res.send(400);
            }
            else {

                //as we have byte data of file, delete the file instance
                try {
                    fs.unlink(fileName);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }

                //now, configure aws

                var s3 = new aws.S3();
                const params = {
                    Bucket: config.AwsS3BucketName, // pass your bucket name
                    Key: fileName, // file will be saved as bucket_name/file.ext
                    Body: data
                }

                //upload file
                s3.upload(params, function (s3Err, awsFileData) {
                    if (s3Err) {
                        console.error(s3Err)
                        res.send(400);
                    } else {
                        console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${awsFileData.Location}`)

                        //update uploaded file data in database using 'models.Users.update'

                        //send response to client/frontend
                        var obj = {};
                        obj.status = { "code": "200", "message": "Yipee!! Its Done" };
                        obj.result = { url: awsFileData.Location };
                        res.status(200).send(obj);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is old school, non - fancy solution.Please try it out and let me know.

Comment: Hey - awesome - definitely not looking for anything fancy. What is the function `getDesiredFileFromPaperclip` ? I think this is only  uploading to s3? The issue is 1. saving the image in the db in that long format that paperclip already is saving it. 2. There are many different sizes, so in S3, there are multiple folders for each size. I need to resize the image into multiple sizes before saving. For example, here is the path to a thumb image `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example/users/avatars/000/000/001/thumb/two_people_talking.gif?1560705432`

Comment: `getDesiredFileFromPaperclip` function returns the image file from paperclip; you can write image related code in it.As commented in the code, you can save your image as a string(though i think saving image link obtained from S3 is better).I don't think saving same image with multiple size is a good option, Add an code to resize image before returning it.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but  you're not addressing my entire question with your answer. The question is much more complex than just uploading an image to S3.